# kindlegen dictionary creation

Tags: kindle, dictionaries, kindlegen

Hi I am trying to create a dictionary for my kindle. 
It is quite a large one, and I've splitted into 16 files each of them are around 20mb. While I am trying to generate the dictionary, kindlegen gives me the following error:

`Error(prcgen):E21013: Two <idx:entry> tags cannot have the same id.`
I have checked the script that is generating the dictionary entries and each file individually, there is simply no identical id fields. Plus it says that the error is found in third file, while `Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file URL:` shows the second file. I tried to put the xhtml files in a different directory as well and refer to them in `metadata.opf` but still I am having the same error

Here is the complete error message:

```
kindlegen metadata.opf -c2 -verbose -o blator.mobi

*************************************************************
 Amazon kindlegen(Linux) V2.9 build 1028-0897292 
 A command line e-book compiler 
 Copyright Amazon.com and its Affiliates 2014 
*************************************************************

Info:I9007:option: -c2: Kindle Huffdic compression
Info:I9014:option: -verbose: Verbose output
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Title        "My Book"
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Creator      "Me and my crew"
Info(prcgen):I1002: Parsing files  0000143
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: blat-0.xhtml
Warning(index build):W15008: language not supported. Using default phonetics for spellchecker: english.
Warning(parser8):W26001: Index not supported for enhanced mobi.
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: blat-1.xhtml
Warning(index build):W15001: inflection rule or rule group too long (max=255). Discarded.
Error(prcgen):E21013: Two <idx:entry> tags cannot have the same id.
```

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing the **complete** error messages and the html sections that they refer to. AFAIK, KindleGen will try to resolve links to other files in the same folder, which might cause this error message, because the **linked** file will contain the **same ids** as the **calling** file.

Comment: @NemoXXX, all right, edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why my solution fixed the error message but I simply removed `id` attribute from `idx:entry` tag, but I left the `id` attribute alone in `a` under `idx:entry`.